# Python str object has no atribute '__getattr__'

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, and I just can't figure out what is wrong her:

```
def SomeDato(): 
  today = datetime.date.today()
  todayStr = idag.strftime('%d.%m.%y')  
  return todayStr

def AnotherFunctionWithinTestComplete()
  strArg = SomeDato()
  datoToCheck = dato.contentText #dato.contentText returns "13.12.15. 16:29"
  if datoToCheck.startswith(strArg):
    do something here....
```

I get this error: `str object has no atribute '__getattr__'` in the line with `if datoToCheck.startswith(strArg)`.

Comment: What are `idag` and `dato`? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

`strftime` is a method of the `datetime` class (somewhat confusingly defined in the `datetime` module) so it is called with

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.strftime(today, '%d.%m.%y')
```

where `today` is a datetime type. This can also be called with `today.strftime('%d.%m.%y')` as an instance method. What is `idag` in your example? The error message indicates that it's a string. If you'd like to convert `idag` into a `datetime` this can be achieved with `datetime.strptime(idag, '%d.%m.%y')` assuming that it is in '%d.%m.%y' format already.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my code is on Danish, and obviously I didn't translate everything. This should be OK now:

```
#returns 13.12.15
def SomeDate(): 
  today = datetime.date.today()
  todayStr = today.strftime('%d.%m.%y')  
  return todayStr

def AnotherFunctionWithinTestComplete()
  # finds an element in the DOM tree 
  date = Aliases.browser.MyPage.FindChildByXPath("some xPath") 
  strArg = SomeDate()
  #date.contentText returns "13.12.15 16:29"
  dateToCheck = date.contentText
  if dateToCheck.startswith(strArg):
    do something here....
```

I've just realized btw, that if I write like this:

```
def AnotherFunctionWithinTestComplete()
  # finds an element in the DOM tree 
  date = Aliases.browser.MyPage.FindChildByXPath("some xPath") 
  strArg = SomeDate()
  #date.contentText returns "13.12.15 16:29"
  dateToCheck = date.contentText + "" 
  if dateToCheck.startswith(strArg):
    do something here....
```

then it is successful. So dateToCheck = date.contentText + "" instead of dateToCheck = date.contentText makes the difference. What's the difference?